# Jboss Server application ip address

Tags: java, jboss, ejb

I'm trying to run jboss on Eclipse, I created an EJB project and it's working and running perfectly, and the files and deploying with no errors or anything, although when I try to go to the localhost and the name of the port I gave it with is 1033 it tells this webpage is not available in this server.

Console:

```
Buildfile: /Users/admin/Documents/test/example-ejb2/ant/start-jboss.xml
startServer:
     [exec] run.sh: Could not set maximum file descriptor limit: unlimited
     [exec] /Users/admin/Jboss/jboss-4.2.3.GA/bin/run.sh: line 89: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Invalid argument
     [exec] =========================================================================
     [exec]   JBoss Bootstrap Environment
     [exec]   JBOSS_HOME: /Users/admin/Jboss/jboss-4.2.3.GA
     [exec]   JAVA: java
     [exec]   JAVA_OPTS: -Dprogram.name=run.sh -Xms128m -Xmx512m -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000
     [exec]   CLASSPATH: /Users/admin/Jboss/jboss-4.2.3.GA/bin/run.jar
     [exec] =========================================================================
     [exec] 15:34:17,285 INFO  [Server] Starting JBoss (MX MicroKernel)...
     [exec] 15:34:17,307 INFO  [Server] Release ID: JBoss [Trinity] 4.2.3.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_4_2_3_GA date=200807181417)
     [exec] 15:34:17,309 INFO  [Server] Home Dir: /Users/admin/Jboss/jboss-4.2.3.GA
     [exec] 15:34:17,309 INFO  [Server] Home URL: file:/Users/admin/Jboss/jboss-4.2.3.GA/
     [exec] 15:34:17,310 INFO  [Server] Patch URL: null
     [exec] 15:34:17,310 INFO  [Server] Server Name: default
     [exec] 15:34:17,310 INFO  [Server] Server Home Dir: /Users/admin/Jboss/jboss-4.2.3.GA/server/default
     [exec] 15:34:17,311 INFO  [Server] Server Home URL: file:/Users/admin/Jboss/jboss-4.2.3.GA/server/default/
     [exec] 15:34:17,311 INFO  [Server] Server Log Dir: /Users/admin/Jboss/jboss-4.2.3.GA/server/default/log
     [exec] 15:34:17,311 INFO  [Server] Server Temp Dir: /Users/admin/Jboss/jboss-4.2.3.GA/server/default/tmp
     [exec] 15:34:17,311 INFO  [Server] Root Deployment Filename: jboss-service.xml
     [exec] 15:34:18,520 INFO  [ServerInfo] Java version: 1.6.0_65,Apple Inc.
     [exec] 15:34:18,520 INFO  [ServerInfo] Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 20.65-b04-462,Apple Inc.
     [exec] 15:34:18,520 INFO  [ServerInfo] OS-System: Mac OS X 10.9,x86_64
     [exec] 15:34:19,102 INFO  [Server] Core system initialized
     [exec] 15:34:20,853 INFO  [WebService] Using RMI server codebase: http://127.0.0.1:8083/
     [exec] 15:34:20,854 INFO  [Log4jService$URLWatchTimerTask] Configuring from URL: resource:jboss-log4j.xml
     [exec] 15:34:21,352 INFO  [TransactionManagerService] JBossTS Transaction Service (JTA version) - JBoss Inc.
     [exec] 15:34:21,352 INFO  [TransactionManagerService] Setting up property manager MBean and JMX layer
     [exec] 15:34:21,466 INFO  [TransactionManagerService] Starting recovery manager
     [exec] 15:34:21,506 INFO  [TransactionManagerService] Recovery manager started
     [exec] 15:34:21,506 INFO  [TransactionManagerService] Binding TransactionManager JNDI Reference
     [exec] 15:34:23,523 INFO  [EJB3Deployer] Starting java:comp multiplexer
     [exec] 15:34:24,919 INFO  [NativeServerConfig] JBoss Web Services - Native
     [exec] 15:34:24,920 INFO  [NativeServerConfig] jbossws-3.0.1-native-2.0.4.GA (build=200803312044)
     [exec] 15:34:25,595 INFO  [Embedded] Catalina naming disabled
     [exec] 15:34:25,688 INFO  [AprLifecycleListener] The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: .:/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java
     [exec] 15:34:25,718 INFO  [Http11Protocol] Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-127.0.0.1-8080
     [exec] 15:34:25,719 INFO  [AjpProtocol] Initializing Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-127.0.0.1-8009
     [exec] 15:34:25,719 INFO  [Catalina] Initialization processed in 124 ms
     [exec] 15:34:25,719 INFO  [StandardService] Starting service jboss.web
     [exec] 15:34:25,720 INFO  [StandardEngine] Starting Servlet Engine: JBossWeb/2.0.1.GA
     [exec] 15:34:25,751 INFO  [Catalina] Server startup in 31 ms
     [exec] 15:34:25,899 INFO  [TomcatDeployer] deploy, ctxPath=/, warUrl=.../deploy/jboss-web.deployer/ROOT.war/
     [exec] 15:34:26,445 INFO  [TomcatDeployer] deploy, ctxPath=/invoker, warUrl=.../deploy/http-invoker.sar/invoker.war/
     [exec] 15:34:26,552 INFO  [TomcatDeployer] deploy, ctxPath=/jbossws, warUrl=.../deploy/jbossws.sar/jbossws-context.war/
     [exec] 15:34:26,623 INFO  [TomcatDeployer] deploy, ctxPath=/jbossmq-httpil, warUrl=.../deploy/jms/jbossmq-httpil.sar/jbossmq-httpil.war/
     [exec] 15:34:27,036 INFO  [TomcatDeployer] deploy, ctxPath=/web-console, warUrl=.../deploy/management/console-mgr.sar/web-console.war/
     [exec] 15:34:27,272 INFO  [MailService] Mail Service bound to java:/Mail
     [exec] 15:34:27,360 INFO  [RARDeployment] Required license terms exist, view META-INF/ra.xml in .../deploy/jboss-ha-local-jdbc.rar
     [exec] 15:34:27,376 INFO  [RARDeployment] Required license terms exist, view META-INF/ra.xml in .../deploy/jboss-ha-xa-jdbc.rar
     [exec] 15:34:27,389 INFO  [RARDeployment] Required license terms exist, view META-INF/ra.xml in .../deploy/jboss-local-jdbc.rar
     [exec] 15:34:27,454 INFO  [RARDeployment] Required license terms exist, view META-INF/ra.xml in .../deploy/jboss-xa-jdbc.rar
     [exec] 15:34:27,505 INFO  [RARDeployment] Required license terms exist, view META-INF/ra.xml in .../deploy/jms/jms-ra.rar
     [exec] 15:34:27,518 INFO  [RARDeployment] Required license terms exist, view META-INF/ra.xml in .../deploy/mail-ra.rar
     [exec] 15:34:27,561 INFO  [RARDeployment] Required license terms exist, view META-INF/ra.xml in .../deploy/quartz-ra.rar
     [exec] 15:34:27,565 INFO  [QuartzResourceAdapter] start quartz!!!
     [exec] 15:34:27,599 INFO  [SimpleThreadPool] Job execution threads will use class loader of thread: main
     [exec] 15:34:27,610 INFO  [QuartzScheduler] Quartz Scheduler v.1.5.2 created.
     [exec] 15:34:27,611 INFO  [RAMJobStore] RAMJobStore initialized.
     [exec] 15:34:27,612 INFO  [StdSchedulerFactory] Quartz scheduler 'DefaultQuartzScheduler' initialized from default resource file in Quartz package: 'quartz.properties'
     [exec] 15:34:27,612 INFO  [StdSchedulerFactory] Quartz scheduler version: 1.5.2
     [exec] 15:34:27,612 INFO  [QuartzScheduler] Scheduler DefaultQuartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.
     [exec] 15:34:28,095 INFO  [ConnectionFactoryBindingService] Bound ConnectionManager 'jboss.jca:service=DataSourceBinding,name=DefaultDS' to JNDI name 'java:DefaultDS'
     [exec] 15:34:28,336 INFO  [A] Bound to JNDI name: queue/A
     [exec] 15:34:28,337 INFO  [B] Bound to JNDI name: queue/B
     [exec] 15:34:28,338 INFO  [C] Bound to JNDI name: queue/C
     [exec] 15:34:28,339 INFO  [D] Bound to JNDI name: queue/D
     [exec] 15:34:28,340 INFO  [ex] Bound to JNDI name: queue/ex
     [exec] 15:34:28,356 INFO  [testTopic] Bound to JNDI name: topic/testTopic
     [exec] 15:34:28,357 INFO  [securedTopic] Bound to JNDI name: topic/securedTopic
     [exec] 15:34:28,358 INFO  [testDurableTopic] Bound to JNDI name: topic/testDurableTopic
     [exec] 15:34:28,359 INFO  [testQueue] Bound to JNDI name: queue/testQueue
     [exec] 15:34:28,378 INFO  [UILServerILService] JBossMQ UIL service available at : /127.0.0.1:8093
     [exec] 15:34:28,411 INFO  [DLQ] Bound to JNDI name: queue/DLQ
     [exec] 15:34:28,482 INFO  [ConnectionFactoryBindingService] Bound ConnectionManager 'jboss.jca:service=ConnectionFactoryBinding,name=JmsXA' to JNDI name 'java:JmsXA'
     [exec] 15:34:28,621 INFO  [JmxKernelAbstraction] creating wrapper delegate for: org.jboss.ejb3.entity.PersistenceUnitDeployment
     [exec] 15:34:28,623 INFO  [JmxKernelAbstraction] installing MBean: persistence.units:jar=example2.jar,unitName=example2 with dependencies:
     [exec] 15:34:28,623 INFO  [JmxKernelAbstraction]   jboss.jca:name=DefaultDS,service=DataSourceBinding
     [exec] 15:34:28,624 INFO  [PersistenceUnitDeployment] Starting persistence unit persistence.units:jar=example2.jar,unitName=example2
     [exec] 15:34:28,650 INFO  [Version] Hibernate EntityManager 3.2.1.GA
     [exec] 15:34:28,660 INFO  [Version] Hibernate Annotations 3.2.1.GA
     [exec] 15:34:28,664 INFO  [Environment] Hibernate 3.2.4.sp1
     [exec] 15:34:28,668 INFO  [Environment] hibernate.properties not found
     [exec] 15:34:28,669 INFO  [Environment] Bytecode provider name : javassist
     [exec] 15:34:28,671 INFO  [Environment] using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
     [exec] 15:34:28,734 INFO  [Ejb3Configuration] found EJB3 Entity bean: ie.dit.ejb.entity.Book
     [exec] 15:34:28,747 INFO  [Configuration] Reading mappings from resource : META-INF/orm.xml
     [exec] 15:34:28,748 INFO  [Ejb3Configuration] [PersistenceUnit: example2] no META-INF/orm.xml found
     [exec] 15:34:28,777 INFO  [AnnotationBinder] Binding entity from annotated class: ie.dit.ejb.entity.Book
     [exec] 15:34:28,783 INFO  [QueryBinder] Binding Named query: Book.findByAuthor => select o from Book o where o.author=:a
     [exec] 15:34:28,783 INFO  [QueryBinder] Binding Named query: Book.findAll => select o from Book o
     [exec] 15:34:28,805 INFO  [EntityBinder] Bind entity ie.dit.ejb.entity.Book on table Book
     [exec] 15:34:28,913 INFO  [ConnectionProviderFactory] Initializing connection provider: org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider
     [exec] 15:34:28,915 INFO  [InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider] Using provided datasource
     [exec] 15:34:28,917 INFO  [SettingsFactory] RDBMS: HSQL Database Engine, version: 1.8.0
     [exec] 15:34:28,918 INFO  [SettingsFactory] JDBC driver: HSQL Database Engine Driver, version: 1.8.0
     [exec] 15:34:28,935 INFO  [Dialect] Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
     [exec] 15:34:28,939 INFO  [TransactionFactoryFactory] Transaction strategy: org.hibernate.ejb.transaction.JoinableCMTTransactionFactory
     [exec] 15:34:28,940 INFO  [TransactionManagerLookupFactory] instantiating TransactionManagerLookup: org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup
     [exec] 15:34:28,941 INFO  [TransactionManagerLookupFactory] instantiated TransactionManagerLookup
     [exec] 15:34:28,941 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Automatic flush during beforeCompletion(): disabled
     [exec] 15:34:28,941 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Automatic session close at end of transaction: disabled
     [exec] 15:34:28,942 INFO  [SettingsFactory] JDBC batch size: 15
     [exec] 15:34:28,942 INFO  [SettingsFactory] JDBC batch updates for versioned data: disabled
     [exec] 15:34:28,942 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Scrollable result sets: enabled
     [exec] 15:34:28,942 INFO  [SettingsFactory] JDBC3 getGeneratedKeys(): disabled
     [exec] 15:34:28,942 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Connection release mode: auto
     [exec] 15:34:28,943 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Default batch fetch size: 1
     [exec] 15:34:28,943 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Generate SQL with comments: disabled
     [exec] 15:34:28,943 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Order SQL updates by primary key: disabled
     [exec] 15:34:28,943 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Order SQL inserts for batching: disabled
     [exec] 15:34:28,943 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Query translator: org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
     [exec] 15:34:28,944 INFO  [ASTQueryTranslatorFactory] Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
     [exec] 15:34:28,944 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Query language substitutions: {}
     [exec] 15:34:28,944 INFO  [SettingsFactory] JPA-QL strict compliance: enabled
     [exec] 15:34:28,945 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Second-level cache: enabled
     [exec] 15:34:28,945 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Query cache: disabled
     [exec] 15:34:28,945 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Cache provider: org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider
     [exec] 15:34:28,945 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Optimize cache for minimal puts: disabled
     [exec] 15:34:28,945 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Cache region prefix: example2_jar,example2
     [exec] 15:34:28,945 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Structured second-level cache entries: disabled
     [exec] 15:34:28,949 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Statistics: disabled
     [exec] 15:34:28,949 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Deleted entity synthetic identifier rollback: disabled
     [exec] 15:34:28,950 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Default entity-mode: pojo
     [exec] 15:34:28,950 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Named query checking : enabled
     [exec] 15:34:28,970 INFO  [SessionFactoryImpl] building session factory
     [exec] 15:34:29,082 INFO  [SessionFactoryObjectFactory] Factory name: persistence.units:jar=example2.jar,unitName=example2
     [exec] 15:34:29,083 INFO  [NamingHelper] JNDI InitialContext properties:{java.naming.factory.initial=org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces}
     [exec] 15:34:29,085 INFO  [SessionFactoryObjectFactory] Bound factory to JNDI name: persistence.units:jar=example2.jar,unitName=example2
     [exec] 15:34:29,085 WARN  [SessionFactoryObjectFactory] InitialContext did not implement EventContext
     [exec] 15:34:29,089 INFO  [SchemaExport] Running hbm2ddl schema export
     [exec] 15:34:29,090 INFO  [SchemaExport] exporting generated schema to database
     [exec] 15:34:29,091 INFO  [SchemaExport] schema export complete
     [exec] 15:34:29,092 INFO  [NamingHelper] JNDI InitialContext properties:{java.naming.factory.initial=org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces}
     [exec] 15:34:29,327 INFO  [JmxKernelAbstraction] creating wrapper delegate for: org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessContainer
     [exec] 15:34:29,329 INFO  [JmxKernelAbstraction] installing MBean: jboss.j2ee:jar=example2.jar,name=BookStore,service=EJB3 with dependencies:
     [exec] 15:34:29,329 INFO  [JmxKernelAbstraction]   persistence.units:jar=example2.jar,unitName=example2
     [exec] 15:34:29,350 INFO  [EJBContainer] STARTED EJB: ie.dit.ejb.session.BookStore ejbName: BookStore
     [exec] 15:34:29,379 INFO  [EJB3Deployer] Deployed: file:/Users/admin/Jboss/jboss-4.2.3.GA/server/default/deploy/example2.jar
     [exec] 15:34:29,405 INFO  [TomcatDeployer] deploy, ctxPath=/jmx-console, warUrl=.../deploy/jmx-console.war/
     [exec] 15:34:29,511 INFO  [Http11Protocol] Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-127.0.0.1-8080
     [exec] 15:34:29,522 INFO  [AjpProtocol] Starting Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-127.0.0.1-8009
     [exec] 15:34:29,530 INFO  [Server] JBoss (MX MicroKernel) [4.2.3.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_4_2_3_GA date=200807181417)] Started in 12s:203ms
```

Am I missing something? or entering the wrong URL? Thanks.

Comment: I don´t understand your question, could you please explain the situation better?

Comment: I'm trying to build an application (just a blank application with just simple text) using EJB though Jboss to view it on the webpage. when I run man ant script it says that it's working and everything is deploying with no errors and my server (localhost:8080) is working but when i enter the server I gave it (env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "localhost:1099");) it doesn't show me anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing your app at 127.0.0.1:1033 instead.

Comment: Just did that, it makes me download a file called "download" with weird characters.